Apache Directory Index: Format of file size
In apache2 Directory Index, is there a way to change the format of file size column from human-readable (M-megabytes, K, T etc) to just bytes?
Name                                            Last modified      Size  Description
Parent Directory                                                     -   
vcruntime140.dll                                2024-05-20 13:11   94K  
vcruntime140_1.dll                              2024-05-20 13:11   36K 
                                                                   ^ change this column to just bytes

In nginx this is set by default, but in apache I struggle to find anything that can be related to configuring this.
Example from nginx: 
vcruntime140.dll                                   08-Sep-2024 00:29               96144
vcruntime140_1.dll                                 08-Sep-2024 00:29               36752

